# Can I install Mavericks side by side with an existing installation?

Tags: macos

My current installation of Mavericks has some issues that can only be fixed with a clean install (no Time Machine restore).

However I don't find time to do the complete reinstall in one session and I still have to work with the current installation.

Now my idea was to install the OS just parallel to the existing Mavericks once more. I have already shrunk my partition (see image). But I fear the second installation will kill my current one if I now just reboot and select to install Mavericks.

Any comments/solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install OSX onto any eligible partition or external drive and are not constrained to simply apply it on the running OS.

Download the installer and choose any destination when it prompts you to install over the running OS.

I prefer this in almost all instances since I can run the migration to my new OS without ever losing my current setup or wiping a system that is currently in use. It only costs disk space and one extra step when installing.

Comment: So I can even continue to work **while** it is installing the OS to a new partition?

Comment: Not really, you will give up control of the Mac for 15 minutes or so while the installer runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a time machine backup you can just wipe the drive, reinstall mavericks and restore from the backup. This can be done in a frw minutes, then just let the data copy over night (or for 1-2 hours depending on how fast your drive is)

Comment: Like I said: TM is not an option because the broken stuff seems to be part of the backup. :-(